Android: When app was opened with click on notification, clicking on further notifications only opens the app, not changing activity
According to this thread on StackOverflow, "Android remembers the intent that was used to launch it". The problem described there is exactly what I'm going through:

When the app is launched for the first time from a Notification, this can mess things up. You launch the app from a Notification and Android remembers the Intent used (from the Notification), when you later launch the app (again from a Notification), android matches the Intent in the Notification with the Intent used to launch the app for the first time, and thinks you want to bring the existing app task from the background to the foreground.

The problem: I don't understand why Android thinks that the Intent is the same. While the activity is the same, the intent has completely different extras.
When I add flags to the intent, I'm able to fix this issue. Like for example:
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

But my goal is to keep the back stack, which it doesn't using these flags of course.
It's a webview app with some additional screens.
The issue only exists when the app is launched through a notification. When I launch it myself and put it to the background, everything works as I wish.
Scenario

not1 = notification with activity MainActivity and extra "openLink" = https://something.com/one
not2 = notification with activity OtherActivity and some extras
not3 = notification with activity MainActivity and extra "openLink" = https://something.com/two


app is closed.

What I want:

user clicks on not1, app launches, opens MainActivity, opens link in webview
user clicks on not2, app opens OtherActivity
user clicks on not3, app opens MainActivity, opens link in webview
user clicks "back", OtherActivity from not2 is shown
user clicks "back", MainActivity from not1 is shown

How it is right now:

user clicks on not1, app launches, opens MainActivity, opens link in webview ✅
user clicks on not2, app opens OtherActivity ✅
user clicks on not3, app opens and shows OtherActivity. Not calling onCreate(). If the app was in background, in calls onResume() of OtherActivity. Even though it was supposed to open MainActivity.

My code:
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    baseContext,
    notificationId,
    newIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)

notificationBuilder = notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())

notificationId is unique. extras of newIntent are unique. I tried every flag there is I believe. MainActivity (which has the webview) has launchMode "singleTop", but of course I tried without setting a launchMode.
Further observations:

If I set android:taskAffinity="" and user clicks on not3 it works, but messes up the back stack. it just pulls the MainActivity in front of the backstack.
I cannot do what Android documentation says, which is to use the TaskStackBuilder, because that doesn't keep the back stack. It just allows you to build your own back stack (impossible with webview)


Interesting situation. Please try this: Add an ACTION to the Intent that you put in the Notification. Set the ACTION to some random string so that it is always unique whenever you create the Notification. Let me know if that helps.

Also, if MainActivity has launch mode singleTop, and the user launches MainActivity from a Notification and then launches MainActivity again from a Notification, this will not create 2 instances of MainActivity on the stack. This may (or may not) be what you want. Your post seems to indicate that you expect to have 2 instances of MainActivity on the stack in this case.

It actually worked, I can't  believe it. Thank you so much! You just made my programming day.
I want infinite amounts of both activities, but only new instances of MainActivity on the stack, if the new intent calls a different activity. Which is exactly what singleTop does, but thanks for the hint.

It's funny, because this is definitely not how you're supposed to use actions... I feel like Android should address this somehow.

I created an answer with more information/explanation. Hopefully this is clear now what was happening and why this change works. You need to make the Intents "different". There are many ways to do this, setting ACTION is one of them.

@DavidWasser what would be another way to make the Intent different? I'm curious. Thanks!

You can make the Intent unique by setting ACTION or DATA to a unique value. You can also set the component name (package, class) but this would cause a different Activity to be launched, so might not help.

Your problem is that when the user taps on not1, Android launches the app with MainActivity and remembers that the app was launched with MainActivity.
When the user taps on not3, the Intent in the Notification has MainActivity, which matches the Intent that was used to launch the app initially. (Note: Android doesn't compare "extras" when comparing Intents.), so Android thinks that you want to bring the existing task containing the app forward from the background, which it does. In this case it doesn't create a new instance of MainActivity, it doesn't call onNewIntent(), it just brings the existing task (in whatever state it was in) to the foreground.
This is the same behaviour as when you are running an app, press HOME, press that app's icon again. Android thinks you want to return to the app, so it just brings it forward from the background.
Solution:
Add an ACTION to the Intent that you put in the Notification. Set the ACTION to some random string so that it is always unique whenever you create the Notification.
This will ensure that whenever a user taps a Notification to launch the app, the Intent will not match the Intent that was used to launch the app initially. Android will then bring the app forward from the background (if it is in the background), create a new instance of the Activity and put that on the task stack.

Just one addition: In my case only the app was opened in its last state. The activity in the intent wasn't even brought into foreground.

That's correct. It just brings the app in whatever state it was in from the background to the foreground. This is exactly what happens when you leave an app (by pressing HOME or a notification or whatever) and then return to it by selecting the app from RECENTS or by pressing the app icon on the HOME screen. You return to the app in exactly the same state as you left it. Same Activity, same Fragment, same data, etc.

A unique action is what makes Android actually differentiate the intents of the same activity:
newIntent.setAction(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
Big thanks to @David Wasser for the solution.

Use only intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Doesn't keep back stack. My question has already been answered.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
